# Why Sed cannot replace lines that contains . + and *

Tags: linux, file, sed

I have a large file and some of the lines are as follows:

```
....    ....+*UNKNOWN*
....    ....+*UNKNOWN*
....    ....+*UNKNOWN*
....    ....+*UNKNOWN*
....    ....+*UNKNOWN*
....    ....+*UNKNOWN*
....    ....+*UNKNOWN*
....    ....+*UNKNOWN*
```

I want to replace ....+*UNKNOWN* part with the `...+PUNCT`

To do that, I did the following:

```
sed 's/\.\.\.\.\+\*UNKNOWN\*/\.\.\.\+PUNCT/g' myfile.out > myfile_result.out
```

However, none of the lines gone.

```
grep -F '...+*UNKNOWN*' myfile.out 

....    ....+*UNKNOWN*
....    ....+*UNKNOWN*
....    ....+*UNKNOWN*
....    ....+*UNKNOWN*
....    ....+*UNKNOWN*
....    ....+*UNKNOWN*
....    ....+*UNKNOWN*
....    ....+*UNKNOWN*
```

I couldn't find my error, could you help me about ?

Comment: You can't just throw a backslash in front of every non-alphabetic character in a regexp and hope for the best. You need to identify which characters are literal, which are metacharacters, and which **become** metacharacters by escaping them and use them appropriately in the context of whichever tool you're using and with whatever options you're providing to that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some versions of `sed`, `\+` has a special meaning, use `+` to match the plus literally.

Comment: what does /+ mean ?

Comment: `\+` means "one or more times", so it's like `*` but it must match at least once.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following.

```
sed 's/+\*UNKNOWN/+PUNCT/'  Input_file
```

**Explanation of + with an example:**

```
echo "This is an example: 123 test 123" | sed -E  's/^[^0-9]*([0-9]+).*/\1/'
123
```

Let's say we have a line `This is an example: 123 test 123` so here `[0-9]+` will match very first set of digits which are coming together and then by keeping them in `sed` 's memory I am printing them by using `\1`(escaping 1 here again to let `sed` know it is the memory sequence I am calling here).

Comment: @EdMorton, apologies for it, I have changed them now. Thanks a TON for your as usual guidance sir.

Answer (score 0):

`\+` in sed means one or more match of the expression preceeded just before '+', means no `+` literal.
To match a literal '+' , use `+`  to match the plus in literal.

Modified expression:

```
sed 's/\.\.\.\.+\*UNKNOWN\*/\.\.\.\+PUNCT/g' myfile.out > myfile_result.out
```